# alignment of footer grid with the body grid

Tags: html, css

I have site http://change.is/ on 
which i have to align footer grid to the body grid.

In footer, there are 4 divs i am using of different colors :-  first & 4th is aligned perfectly with the body grid but problem is for 2 & 3 div.

i changed the background image postion of 2 & 3 div to make it align with the body grid at browser 100% zoom level 
but when we zoom in & out then 2 & 3 divs not stayed aligned to the body grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define **background-attachment:fixed** to them. Write like this:

```
.lessons {
    background: url("../images/f2.png") repeat fixed -80px -12px transparent;
}
.mentors {
    background: url("../images/f3.png") repeat fixed -80px -12px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the narrow width you switch the `background-attachment` property from `fixed` to `scroll`:

In `styles_desktop.css`:

```
.lessons { background:url("../images/f2.png") repeat fixed -80px -39px transparent;
```

In `styles_tablet.css`:

```
.lessons { background:url("../images/f3.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Change `scroll` to `fixed` in the tablets rule and it should work.

Nice looking site btw.